# How can i translate this into Vb.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I am trying to translate this piece of code into VB.NET using this [tool](http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/), but the translation is not working,

Original C# code,

```
public void Init(HttpApplication application)
{
    application.Error += new System.EventHandler(OnError);
}
```

Translated,

```
Public Sub Init(application As HttpApplication)
    application.[Error] += New System.EventHandler(AddressOf OnError)
End Sub
```

But the translation is giving me errors, I am new to VB.NET.

I think it's very straight forward. I am not a VB.NET developer and do not quite understand how to translate so I could only recur to the translation website mentioned above but unfortunately the translated version did not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`AddHandler`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7taxzxka.aspx) keyword instead of `+=` operator:

```
AddHandler application.[Error], AddressOf OnError
```

Comment: Is HandleStart an ASP thing?

Comment: Minor point - you only need the square brackets for unqualified uses of keywords in VB, so AddHandler application.Error, AddressOf OnError is fine.